# Straightening curled in file-folders

Tags: storage, stationery, plastics

Going to my workplace, I usually place file-folders in my bag (see figure 1).

[image: figure 1: file-folder]

However, after some time of using this file-folder, the top and top-right are both curled into the middle (see figure 2), between the front and back sheets of the file-folder.

[image: figure 2:]

**How can I straighten the top and top-right so that it no longer curls inward?**

or

**How can I prevent new file-folders from curling inward when placed in my bag?**

I have tried flattening it with my hands and placing it under a heavy object for a few days. This lessens the curls, but eventually returns to the curled-in state after placing it in my bag again.

Answer (score 1):

Transport your file folders in a bag with hard sides, the bag being slightly bigger than the folders and the folders snug against the (hard) side of the compartment or bag.

Do not allow them space to move in the bag. Fill the bag or part of the bag if needed.

If you do not have such a bag, you can make a folder transport case by using two boards bigger than your folders and elastic bands.

You can also make a folder holder by using duck tape or an other fabric tape, and two boards that are big enough. Connect the boards with the tape so that there is space between the boards and the sticky side of the tape is all covered by other bits of tape.

Whether you can rescue the folders already damaged depends on what they are made from and how much work you do on them. If they are beyond rescue or you can not find out how to get them back into good shape, you might be able to still use them if you put something thin and hard inside, like a sheet of (non rusting) metal or thin hard plastic.

If you tell use what your file folders are made out of maybe someone can tell you what the best method is to unbent them, but most materials stay weak when they have been bend before.

Comment: A similar idea: buy one or more clipboards and either clip your folders to them before putting them in your bag, or simply use the clipboards to reinforce the bag and keep it straight & rigid.